# How to get adblock in GeckoFX Windows Forms webbrowser?

Tags: c#, geckofx, adblock

I am using GeckoFX45 to run a browser in Windows Forms. I want to be able to add an adblocker (uBlock or AdBlock Plus).

Most of the adblockers are for IE, and  `GeckoPreferences.Default("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False;` gives me an error.

Is there a way to implement an Adblock into the GeckoFX browser?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to add Firefox extensions to GeckoFX

First, add the location where the extension is deployed using

```
Xpcom.ComponentRegistrar.AutoRegister():

void RegisterExtensionDir(string dir)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Registering binary extension directory:  " + dir);
        var chromeDir = (nsIFile)Xpcom.NewNativeLocalFile(dir);
        var chromeFile = chromeDir.Clone();
        chromeFile.Append(new nsAString("chrome.manifest"));
        Xpcom.ComponentRegistrar.AutoRegister(chromeFile);
}
```

> Second, do NOT use the ABI flag in the extension's chrome.manifest. So
>   instead of

```
binary-component components/GeckoScraper.dll  ABI=WINNT_x86-msvc
```

> use

```
binary-component components/GeckoScraper.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly because Firefox extensions are largely based around the interface and working of Firefox's UI, not just the Gecko interface, I don't think it would be possible at all currently to install extensions or .XPI files.

So in order to do this without using an extension, you may have to code an adblocker yourself which I've been trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718536/build-an-adblocker-for-geckofx-browser-in-winform).

Otherwise, good luck! I've been having similar issues and am looking towards writing my own solution.